# My Apc Thread is terminated..why not....?(queue user apc code injection..)

Tags: code-injection

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void CALLBACK Message()
{
    SleepEx(1000,TRUE);

    MessageBox(
        NULL,
        "QueueUserAPC Injection",
        "Thread",
        NULL
    );
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if(0)
        Message();

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\바탕 화면\\NOTEPAD_bak_org.EXE",        // Command line

        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable

        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable

        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE

        0x8000004,              // No creation flags

        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block

        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 

        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure

        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )



    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return 0;
    }



    LPVOID original_p = VirtualAlloc(0,0x6000,0x3000,0x40);



    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(),(LPCVOID)0x00400000,original_p,0x6000,0);



    LPVOID target_p = VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess,0,0x6000,0x3000,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);



    WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess,target_p,original_p,0x6000,0);



    //VirtualFree(original_p,dwsize,0x8000);



    DWORD Eip = (DWORD) target_p + 0x1000;



    QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC) Eip, pi.hThread, 0);



    SleepEx(1000,TRUE);



    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);





    getchar();

    return 0;

}
```

i want to excute other process injected code(message box call) altough resume thread was excuted, Messagebox is not excuted.. why..?

i certainly check otherprocess injected code!!

please.. help

Answer (score 0):

of course this code will be not work. you only copy part of self code to another process. but how about imports ? you think about this ? relocs ? nothing will be worked